# Facebook PHP SDK 4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post to a group in facebook that is managed by me via a facebook app. The funny thing if I log into facebook with my the admin account of the app, then I can see the posts in the group, but if I ask some friend who is also in that group, then he cannot see the posts made via the app. I guess, my app is still running in the Sandbox. Could you let me know if Facebook allows to make automatic posts to a Facebook group where I am the admin? Essentially, my group is about housing offers in a city and I'd like my app to post automatically new offers into my group such that other people can see them as well.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be any restrictions for posts showing up within a Group when posting updates via the API. It could be that posts needs to be approved by the Group Administrator before they appear to users.

If you app is in Sandbox Mode, updates won't appear until you make the app public. You can do this without having to submit permissions for review. As soon as the app is made public, the posts will appear within the group.

If you are the administrator of the group, check the Group Settings to see if posts require approval.